# Upgrading to 6.5

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

After start tor-browser on debian wheezy it tried to upgrade to 6.5 version. It automatically downloaded asc, xz and failed on verifying. I made so several times, then go to https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/6.5/ and downloaded myself both. Both are same checked with diff3. After failed verifying, obviously, cannot upgrade. What can be reason? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/260

Comment: I am also having issue with TorBrowser 6.5 on macOS – please let me know what relevant details I can provide to help diagnose + fix.

Comment: I saw https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/260            Is there some way other to waiting debian maintaineer , for example suspend/not upgrade to 6.5? Such problems will be in future also.

Comment: Careful! This is not a question about Tor Browser; it is a question about a separate thing, which is an unrelated Debian package named torbrowser-launcher. People who use Tor Browser, and let it update itself the way it does by default, will not encounter this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Debian Wheezy found following:

update/refresh keys from mit using command

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys
```

after this `torbrowser-launcher` upgrades itself successfully.

Thanks to Vika^ from #tor